# ArrayList / for-loop

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

My problem is simple : `listeBalles` is an `ArrayList<Balle>` and here is my code :

```
for (Balle b : listeBalles) {

        b.changeList(listeBalles);        
}
```

The matter is that the method `b.changeList` adds a Balle to the ArrayList `listeBalles`. I think that this is the matter. Here are the exceptions :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:372)

at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:343)

at Main.main(Main.java:31)
```

The line pointed is the `for (Balle b : listeBalles) {` line.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847695/java-delete-arraylist-iterator for the remove case and how this problem is addressed

Comment: @demongolem add is different than remove I think. E.g. there is no support in the Iterator to add elements.

Comment: Ok, then I submit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993025/java-adding-elements-to-a-collection-during-iteration for your consideration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you cannot add elements to an `ArrayList` you're currently iterating over, make a copy of that list first.

E.g. try:

```
for (Balle b : new ArrayList(listeBalles)) {
        b.changeList(listeBalles);         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right. From `ArrayList`'s JavaDoc:

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator
>   methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException.

So basically you're not allowed to modify the List during iterating over it. What is your actual question?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I need to do that so I used Puce's code and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is that you are iterating through the `List` and modifying it at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the content of a collection or array while you iterate over it in a for-each loop. What are you actually trying to do?